# Maven Assembly with external jar's

Tags: java, maven, jar, maven-assembly-plugin

I am trying to create an assembly (a runnable jar, that is), and would like to have all the EXTERNAL jar's to be included in my assembly in "jar" format, rather than the classes from external jar's taken out and being made part of my "runnable" jar file. 
I have tried using the "unpack" option (setting it to false) in the assembly file but it creates other problems, like, it doesn't generate the CLASS files for my project, let alone including dealing with external jar files. So I am definitely doing something wrong. 
Help would be greatly appreciated. 
POM and ASSEMBLY info below.
Thanks

Here is a snippet from my POM file.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <descriptors>
            <descriptor>src/assembly/assemblyinfo.xml</descriptor>
        </descriptors>
        <archive>
            <manifest>
                <mainClass>com.company.sample</mainClass>
            </manifest>
        </archive>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>single</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

And here is assemblyinfo.xml

```
<assembly xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/ASSEMBLY/2.0.0"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/ASSEMBLY/2.0.0                   http://maven.apache.org/xsd/assembly-2.0.0.xsd">
  <id>FULL</id>
  <formats>
    <format>jar</format>
  </formats>
  <includeBaseDirectory>false</includeBaseDirectory>
  <dependencySets>
    <dependencySet>
      <outputDirectory>/</outputDirectory>
      <useProjectArtifact>true</useProjectArtifact>
      <unpack>true</unpack>
      <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependencySet>
  </dependencySets>
</assembly>
```

Comment: can you please post the answer if possible?

Answer (score 0):

```html
<build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <configuration>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <mainClass>com.evermore.talos.services.ttservice.ttstarter.UIStartup</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>make-assembly</id> <!-- this is used for inheritance merges -->
                        <phase>compile</phase> <!-- bind to the packaging phase -->
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.7</version>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.shared</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-filtering</artifactId>
                        <version>1.3</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>copy-resources</id>
                        <!-- here the phase you need -->
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${basedir}/target/release</outputDirectory>
                            <resources>
                                <resource>
                                    <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                                    <filtering>true</filtering>
                                </resource>
                                <resource>
                                    <directory>target</directory>
                                    <includes>
                                        <include>*-dependencies.jar</include>
                                    </includes>
                                </resource>
                            </resources>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>
```

Plese refer this Maven build settings. This is how we build executable jar with all dependencies.

Comment: Thanks Shineed. Appreciate your quick response.
I am trying to avoid "jar-with-dependencies" decscriptorRef and the reason is that I'd like to be able to give my own "name" for the assembly. For example, in the assemblyinfo.xml, you see the name as <id> FULL </id>. it appends the "_FULL" at the end of the jar file. So, the final JAR file will be like MyZookeeperexample_1_FULL.jar instead of  "MyZookeeperexample_1_jar-with-dependencies.jar"

Comment: Also, when you use "jar-with-dependency", the external JAR are "unpacked" which means you end up with a bunch of CLASS files and that's exactly what I am trying to avoid.